# How to apply CSS on alternate elements with certain data-value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am typing to apply css on alternate elements which have `[data-row="row"]`

**Something like:**

```css
[data-row="row"]:nth-of-type(odd) {
  background-color: #B7CEEC;
}
```

```html
<div class="pricingdiv" style="width:100%;min-height: 100px;background-color:white;">
  <ol class="pricingList">
    <li class="LotLi">
      <div class="addedlot" data-row="row" title="Left Click to see Details. Right Click to Add Lineitem." data-lot="txtlottitle~Lot Title^lotstextarea~&quot;asdad&quot;^file_uploadlot~LotFile472cb2d^lottype~value^txtbiddecrement~123^txtfrontbuffer~^txtbackbuffer~">Lot Title-"asdad" <span><input class="chkdeletelot" style="float:left;" value="delete" type="checkbox"> </span>  <span class="deletelotli" style="float:right;cursor: pointer;cursor: hand;color:red; ">delete</span>
      </div>
      <ol class="lotchildlist">
        <li class="LineitemLi" title="Left Click to see more.">
          <div class="addedlineitem" data-row="row" data-ceilingprice="123" data-historicprice="123" data-reserveprice="3" data-quantity="2332" data-extendedprice="2" data-saving="23">LineItem Title <span> <input class="chkdeletelineitem" style="float:left;" value="delete" type="checkbox"> </span><span class="ceilingprice" style="padding-left:130px">123</span>  <span clas="quantity" style="padding-left:130px">2332</span> 
            <span
            class="extendedprice" style="padding-left:130px">'2'</span> <span class="saving" style="padding-left:130px">'23'</span>  <span class="deletelineitemli" style="float:right;cursor: pointer;cursor: hand;color:red; ">delete</span>
              <div class="lineitemdescription" data-row="row">'ads'</div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="LineitemLi" title="Left Click to see more.">
          <div class="addedlineitem" data-row="row" data-ceilingprice="342" data-historicprice="2323" data-reserveprice="432" data-quantity="33" data-extendedprice="434" data-saving="">LineItem Title <span> <input class="chkdeletelineitem" style="float:left;" value="delete" type="checkbox"> </span><span class="ceilingprice" style="padding-left:130px">342</span>  <span class="quantity" style="padding-left:130px">33</span> 
            <span
            class="extendedprice" style="padding-left:130px">'434'</span> <span class="saving" style="padding-left:130px">''</span>  <span class="deletelineitemli" style="float:right;cursor: pointer;cursor: hand;color:red; ">delete</span>
              <div class="lineitemdescription" data-row="row">'asdad'</div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="LotLi">
      <div class="addedlot" data-row="row" title="Left Click to see Details. Right Click to Add Lineitem." data-lot="txtlottitle~Lot Title2^lotstextarea~&quot;asdad&quot;^file_uploadlot~LotFile6b238d6^lottype~value^txtbiddecrement~23^txtfrontbuffer~^txtbackbuffer~">Lot Title2-"asdad" <span><input class="chkdeletelot" style="float:left;" value="delete" type="checkbox"> </span>  <span class="deletelotli" style="float:right;cursor: pointer;cursor: hand;color:red; ">delete</span>
      </div>
      <ol class="lotchildlist">
        <li class="LineitemLi" title="Left Click to see more.">
          <div class="addedlineitem" data-row="row" data-ceilingprice="123" data-historicprice="123" data-reserveprice="23" data-quantity="232" data-extendedprice="23" data-saving="23">LineItem Title <span> <input class="chkdeletelineitem" style="float:left;" value="delete" type="checkbox"> </span><span class="ceilingprice" style="padding-left:130px">123</span>  <span class="quantity" style="padding-left:130px">232</span> 
            <span
            class="extendedprice" style="padding-left:130px">'23'</span> <span class="saving" style="padding-left:130px">'23'</span>  <span class="deletelineitemli" style="float:right;cursor: pointer;cursor: hand;color:red; ">delete</span>
              <div class="lineitemdescription" data-row="row">'asd'</div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

I would prefer pure CSS solution to this. Thanks.

Comment: Is that *odd* in relation to the `<li>`, or *odd* in relation to the entire DOM?

Comment: @RGraham I have hardcoded the colors http://jsfiddle.net/uqs9znog/
so that you can get a better understanding of my question

Comment: I suspect this is not possible with CSS unless all the `data-row` divs share a parent.

Answer (score 1):

**DEMO IS [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hy0z7swv/1/)**

```
.pricingList > li:nth-of-type(odd)>div[data-row="row"] {
  background-color: red;
}
.pricingList > li:nth-of-type(even)>div[data-row="row"]{
    background-color: blue;
}
.pricingList > li:nth-of-type(odd) ol li:nth-of-type(odd) [data-row="row"]{
    background-color: blue;
}
.pricingList > li:nth-of-type(odd) ol li:nth-of-type(even) [data-row="row"]{
    background-color: red;
}
.pricingList > li:nth-of-type(even) ol li:nth-of-type(odd) [data-row="row"]{
    background-color: red;
}
.pricingList > li:nth-of-type(even) ol li:nth-of-type(even) [data-row="row"]{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: That demo highlights *even* rows. And is also not representative of the problem because all your rows are siblings

Comment: So now I have to ask. What's different between this and the asker's original CSS: `[data-row="row"]:nth-of-type(odd)`?

Comment: This doesnt work. My scenario is different.  The divs might not necessarily be siblings. There can be parent child relationship. Can you make it work in my snippet?

Comment: @venkat7668  I have hard coded the colors so that you can get a better insight http://jsfiddle.net/uqs9znog/
This is what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

The alternating rows are the li, in which you have the data-row attribute. So:

```
li:nth-of-type(odd) [data-row="row"] {
    background-color: #B7CEEC;
}
```

Comment: his doesnt work. My scenario is different. The divs might not necessarily be siblings. There can be parent child relationship. Can you make it work in my snippet?